# svg Size Resizing dynamically with screen size

Tags: php, css, svg

i like to make a svg and change size when the screen is change in php file .

I tried putting a php variable in the size of the svg which worked but I couldn't bind it to the screen size

Answer (score 1):

I fix two div
if screen size is small run the first else run the other

```
 <div class="small"> <?php 
   $myVar=100;
   echo'<svg width="'.$myVar.'" height="'.$myVar.'">';
   echo'<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="4"      fill="green" />';
   echo'</svg> ';
    ?>
 </div>
 <div class="big"> <?php
    $myVar=500;
    echo'<svg width="'.$myVar.'" height="'.$myVar.'">';
    echo'<circle cx="300" cy="300" r="90" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"     fill="purple" />';
    echo'</svg> ';
    ?>
  </div>
```

and css

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
.small{
  display: block;
  }
.big{
  display: none;
  }
   }

 @media screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
  .small{
    display: none;
    }
  .big{
    display: block;
    }
    }
```